# Oracle - Merge. It does the update but not the insert (dbfiddle inside)

Tags: oracle, merge, insert

I'm trying to use the MERGE function :

see example :

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3f49d206f5a82d88112387c049d441cb

Update is OK :

```
1000    150     1   YES
1001    150     1   YES
1003    150     1   YES
```

But my dream is to get this :

```
1000    150     1   YES
1001    150     1   YES
1002    150     1   YES
1003    150     1   YES
```

Why don't I find the 1002 ?
Something wrong on my MERGE probably, but I don't understand the problem.

Could you help me please ? :-)

Thanks,

Abou Ilyès

Comment: It's because of your condition `WHERE CODEAXESTAT='150'`. This condition is only fetching 3 rows. Just remove this condition, you will get multiple rows.

Comment: Hello, yes indeed ! But, in that case, it work once, but updated me all my records in the table STATS_CLIENT_TEST . See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=639ae779d3f01a9a0585ef7badba866f

Comment: Its totally unclear what is your end result. Please post here what you actually want on your table.

Comment: I would like get this : 

1000    150     1   YES  ||
1001    150     1   YES  ||
1002    150     1   YES  ||
1003    150     1   YES  ||  edit : sorry, I dont know how to format to display as a table in this mini answer, but just have a look on the first message "But my dream is to get this :"

Comment: Dont you think using only `SELECT DISTINCT *` will give your end result.

Answer (score 0):

In your source table the key for 1002 already exists
merge is doing what it should be , updating when condition matches and not doing anything when the key is already present.

```
SELECT * from STATS_CLIENT_TEST;
```

below is screenshot from your fiddle, check that id 1002 is already available in the table.
[image]

in you update part, you are setting this field "codeaxestat" exactly same as it is before , you have the same value in where clause ?

```
               s.codeaxestat= '150', 
               s.codeelementstat = '1',
               s.valeuraxestatistiqueclient='YES'
                        
     WHERE codeaxestat='150'
```